# How to get the Paragraph style from w:sdtContent in word XML

Tags: xml, vba, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

I need to get the style of a paragraph to which i have assigned tag value ( COntentControl ).
Now i have added contentControl (ie) Tag value to the paragraph in word,I can able to get the text of that corresponding paragraph to which i have assigned a tag value,

```
case "DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.SdtBlock":
    SdtBlock p1 = (SdtBlock)DocElement;
    string content1 = p1.InnerText;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(content1))
        dt.Rows.Add(content1);
    break;
```

and am adding that para to the table , but i need to get the style of the para ,when i saved the word document in XML format i get these codes

```
    <w:sdtContent>
        <w:p w:rsidR="00D57D79" w:rsidRDefault="00176023">
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman"/>
                    <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="auto"/>
                    <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
                </w:rPr>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman"/>
                    <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="auto"/>
                    <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t>Use Case Model</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
    </w:sdtContent>
</w:sdt>
```

I need to get the corresponding style of that paragraph.How to get those styles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 case "DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.SdtBlock":
                        SdtBlock p1 = (SdtBlock)DocElement;
                        content1 = p1.InnerText;

                        IEnumerable<Paragraph> pp = p1.Descendants<Paragraph>();
                        foreach (Paragraph para in pp)
                        {
                         style=   GetParagraphStyleId(para);
                        }
```

where  **GetParagraphStyleId(para)**  has

```
 public string GetParagraphStyleId(Paragraph p)
    {
        string ParaStyleIdValue = string.Empty;
        if (p.ParagraphProperties != null)
        {
            if (p.ParagraphProperties.ParagraphStyleId != null)
            {
                if (p.ParagraphProperties.ParagraphStyleId.Val != null)
                {
                    ParaStyleIdValue = p.ParagraphProperties.ParagraphStyleId.Val.Value;
                }
            }
        }
        return ParaStyleIdValue;
    }

  Using this i get the Style of the paragraph from sdtContent.
```